# perl regex expression extraction

Tags: regex, perl

how to extract this string using regular expression

```
||03/15/2012||10:17:11|FOR TEST
```

I want to extract "03/15/2012" . I have tried this command

```
my $firstLine =~ m/^\|\|\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\|\|/i ;
trace("first line extraction : $firstLine first $1");
```

It doesn't work. could you please help ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a capturing group `()` around the part you want to extract:

```perl
my $line = '||03/15/2012||10:17:11|FOR TEST';
if ($line =~ m/^\|\|(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\|\|/i) {
  # Capturing group ┴───────────────────┘
  print("Group 1: $1\n"); # 03/15/2012
}
```

Comment: correct. but why I can't do an assignment, like my $data = $1

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value of the a capturing group directly like this:

```
my $in = "||03/15/2012||10:17:11|FOR TEST";
(my $Date) = $in =~ /^\|\|(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\|\|/;
```

You will find the result of the capturing group 1 in `$Date`.

Btw. you don't need the modifier `i`, because this makes letters matching case insensitive, since you have no letters in your regex, this option is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `my $firstLine =~m/^\|\|(.+)\|\|.*$/i`

You only really care about what's between the first two sets of double pipes

Answer (score 0):

***Script***:

```
my $firstLine = '||03/15/2012||10:17:11|FOR TEST';
print $1 if $firstLine =~ /(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/;
```

***Output:***

```
03/15/2012
```

Test this code here: http://ideone.com/99iUg

Comment: If the line **always** starts with **||** followed by date, then you can replace regex `/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/` with this one: `/^\|{2}(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/`.